# Text classification using charAt() do not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to distinguish the values entered by the user.

Users use an input form to add values.

If `'#'` is the front of the value entered by the user. remove `'#'` and redirect to A

other than that redirect to B

I tried to distinguish this by using charAt() but do not work

also i don't know .replace() is working

That code only goes to the current URL + /?, whatever i type.

please help me

```html
<form>
  <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." +
         style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;"> 
  <input onclick="return findSharp()" type="submit" 
         value="Search" style="background:#222;">
</form>
<script>
  function findSharp(){
    var stringName = document.getElementById("pathID").value;
    if(stringName.charAt(0) == '#'){
      findURLA()
    } else {
      findURLB()
    }
  }
                       
  function findURLA(){
    var hashId = document.getElementById("pathID").value;
    var hashIdReplace = hashId.replace('#','');
    window.location.href = 
      'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 
      'hashtag/' + hashIdReplace;
      return false;
  }
                       
  function findeURLB(){
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/';
    document.write("I AM URL B");
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are using the `click` event of a `submit` button and both potential return values are `false`, meaning that you always want to cancel the `click`. In this case, you really shouldn't be using a `form` and `submit` button in the first place.

Comment: You have a typo in code :  `findURLB()` and function `findeURLB()` note the **e** that's the problem.

Comment: other wise code is works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on me, also tested, the only thing is that it has an error:

`function findeURLB(){`

it should be:

`function findURLB(){`

**UPDATE:**

you might try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8CVOXEIMCEL)

Comment: did it work now? It works on me when I fixed the typo error

Comment: i'm try to 'Rinkesh Golwala' 's answer and fixed the type error, findURLA is worked but findURLB is do not work...

Comment: @Kimchiman I don't actually know what was wrong, but you can try the update that I made. It shows A and B are working.

Comment: your code is working on that site, but B do not working on my system...T.T I don't know why don't worked B in my system.../ i type "#test'. A is good, i type 'test' and click seach button but don't act search button...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
          function findSharp(){
                var stringName = 
                document.getElementById("pathID").value;
                if(stringName[0] == '#'){
                    findURLA(stringName.slice(1,))
                }
                else{
                    findURLB(stringName)
                }
            }

            function findURLA(hashId){
                window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 'hashtag/' + hashId;
            }

            function findURLB(hashId){
                window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/';
                document.write("I AM URL B");
            }
```

Comment: An answer should (at the very least) explain what it does and why.

Comment: This code do working findURLA, but do not working findURLB... Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I change a little bit your code in few places

- give `event` and `event.preventDefault()` to findSharp function for remove return statement from html (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769527/860099))
- add parameters to findURLAA and findURLB (and fix typeo error in that second function name) to omit repeated reading and remove coupling thath functions with global/html variables
- temporary comment findURL-A/B content - you can uncomment it

```js
function findSharp(event) {
  var path = pathID.value;

  if (path[0] == '#') {
    findURLA(path)
  } else {
    findURLB(path)
  }
  event.preventDefault(); // not change location by form
}

function findURLA(path) {
  var hashIdReplace = path.replace('#', '');
  console.log('A:', hashIdReplace)
  // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 'hashtag/' + hashIdReplace;
}

function findURLB(path) {
  console.log('B:', path)
  //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/';
  //document.write("I AM URL B");

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;">
  <input onclick="findSharp(event)" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: @Kimchiman - what is the error message or problem with that code in your system? (and what system you use?)

Comment: i'm using wordpress on my ESXi,  I am a beginner...
I don't know how to look at the error message...